# Disable specific view display in drupal 8 via database or programmatically

Tags: views

I was modifying a display mode in my view and must have added a criteria which doesn't exist and when I saved my changes, I was immediately thrown to a wsod.  After checking the logs, here is the error that I've found:

```
Exception: No entity type for field vid on view newsletters in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (line 697 of /home/admin/domains/zend8.sitesbycoop.com/public_html/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/HandlerBase.php).
```

Does anyone know of a way to disable this view mode via the database or programmatically so I'm not locked out of my view anymore?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In D8 views are configuration.

If you can use the admin ui, go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`, choose *Configuration Type* `View` and the view you want to change, modify it and paste in the single import section.

If you can't access the admin ui, you can use drush:

```
drush cedit views.view.newsletters
```